# Best plugin for html table pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

There is lots of plugins but are there any good ones? What do you use in your projects?

Comment: People, Don't be so lazy to search over Internet! https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=jquery+datagrid+paging

Comment: Not a straight-forward question and potentially causes a discussion... i.e. violates website rules. Just sayin'.

Comment: This question is not very constructive. It invites debate due to its subjectivity. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: @IgorPopov I have been searching. I wrote that it is a lot of plugins out there.

Answer (score 4):

I used [datatables](http://datatables.net) for dynamically loaded tables and it worked for me.

http://datatables.net

Answer (score 0):

i am using this in my project and it's really awesome.

http://flexigrid.info/

Answer (score 0):

Working on 2 projects at the moment, wrote my own in the other one and using [datatables](http://datatables.net/) in the other.